# Is it acceptable for people with suspended accounts to post during suspension with other accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I'm asking because it seems to be happening. Also, I suspect ["sockpuppetry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)) investigations are complex to conduct, so I'm not trying to rush anything, but I've raised some such flags about a week ago... Does progress on those depend e.g. on cooperation from the SE staff?

---

A bit of searching found a [relevant page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange) on the "big meta"

> When should sockpuppets be considered a problem?
>
> [...] if the second account allows you to do something on the site that your normal account would be prevented from doing, it is abuse. Examples of this include (but are not limited to): [...]
>
> Circumventing suspensions, quality bans [...]

Comment: No, this is not acceptable and yes, sometimes investigating these requires a Community Manager and there are currently only 4 of them. (I don't know anything about the case you're referring to; I'm speaking as a moderator on other sites in the network.)

Comment: The title and the body of this question seem to be very different. Can you please post one question at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a secondary account to evade any kind of block is indeed an abuse of the system.

However, it's also something that we tend to tolerate - at least until the secondary account becomes disruptive. Most times we do this to collect more data points and handle the case a bit more effectively. There's also a small chance the user has learned their lesson. It's rare, but I have seen accounts that started out as sockpuppets grow into model citizens.

---

Sockpuppet investigations can be particularly complex and time-consuming. The tools we have at our disposal are far from perfect. And there are several cases where we must call upon SE for help - voting fraud and network-wide issues are the more common ones.

When we do involve SE, it may take a while before we hear back. If memory serves the longest I've waited was a couple of months - and this was before the [CM team was downsized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342039/firing-community-managers-stack-exchange-is-not-interested-in-cooperating-with).

That said if there's any real urgency we can always ping someone directly.

---

About your flags:

This was me being lazy. We are aware of the situation, I should have cleared the flags earlier.

Comment: "Sockpuppet investigations can be particularly complex and time-consuming" I'd love to expand on that but we've been asked to avoid sharing details about the tools and processes, as we could accidentally reveal potential exploits.

Comment: I guess it depends on the offense, but I'm not all that comfortable with tolerating bypassing a suspension like this. Especially longer suspension normally do not come out of nothing; first there are warnings, short suspension, etc. Especially for CoC violations, in my experience users are unlikely to stop entirely, and will again test out the limits of what is possible. Subjecting the users here to that if it's not absolutely necessary for the process doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: @tim It's case by case. I have in the past removed sockpuppet accounts on sight, with no prior warning (remember the fascism troll?). And yes, CoC violations call for immediate action - I won't knowingly let someone go around insulting people just because I need to collect a few more data points to verify sockpuppetry.

Answer (score 2):

This was asked on Meta.SO and [the list of bad things to use sockpuppets for includes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388985/2370483)

> - using multiple accounts to circumvent system-imposed restrictions.
> - using alternative accounts to circumvent suspension by a moderator.

Comment: Strangely enough, the other A here says 'tolerated, if not also disruptive', and the msg sent is 'your *account* has been suspended'. From both I'd conclude that alternate personality/account action *is allowed?* The 'circumvention' would then mean: 'use non-main (main=suspended) account to repeat/continue actions that did cause trouble for main account'? Not: have multiple accounts, get into trouble with one, with susoension, the refrain from all actions as long as the one is 'in jail'?